# How can I start Tango & Cash

Tags: the-secret-world

There is a quest in the junk yard called Tango & Cash where you are supposed to try and break the record at mob killing the two dogs have. The first step says to go to the barriers and prepare. I have spent over an hour now walking around the area. I know where the barriers are but the quest never progresses. I thought maybe the quest It takes two to Tango was holding it up some how so I went and did that one, but still no luck.. The 'Regular' attacks do not appear to be that regular.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mission is meant to be done in tandem with Edgar's **Scrapyard Defense** mission, which is what triggers the attacks. If you've already completed that one before, remember you can repeat any mission after 24 hours. Alternatively you can wait for someone else to do them and help them out - you both get kill credit that way and they might appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was on another quest that taking that one would have canceled at the time so I passed it by and was just in 'Finish these quests before I get more' mode :)

Comment: This took me a while to figure out, because there were other people around triggering the attacks but I never managed to catch them at the right timing to clear this.